# Parse JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I use [JSON.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) and I would like to parse the following object which I get from a WebService. Can someone post an example on how to do that?

```
@"{""MessageType"":0,
   ""Message"":""Success"",
   ""Value"":[
              {""listId"":1,
               ""listName"":""DemoList"",
               ""itemInList"":[
                    {
                     ""fromDate"":""\/Date(1228946400000)\/"",
                     ""fromLocation"":null,
                     ""toLocation"":null,
                     ""originalRequest"":""water"",
                     ""creationDate"":""\/Date(1339448400000)\/"",
                     ""typeId"":1
                    },
                    {
                     ""fromDate"":null,
                     ""fromLocation"":null,
                     ""toLocation"":null,
                     ""originalRequest"":""gala"",
                     ""creationDate"":""\/Date(1304370000000)\/"",
                     ""typeId"":1
                    }
              ]}
    ]}"
```

JSON Object

```
{
  "MessageType":0,
  "Message":"UserLists",
  "Value":
          [
            {
              "listId":1,
              "listName":"DemoList",
              "itemInList" 
                    [
                      {
                         "fromDate":"\/Date(1228946400000)\/",
                         "fromLocation":null,
                         "toLocation":null,
                         "originalRequest":"water",
                         "creationDate":"\/Date(1339448400000)\/",
                         "typeId":1
                      },
                      {
                         "fromDate":null,
                         "fromLocation":null,
                         "toLocation":null,
                         "originalRequest":"gala",
                         "creationDate":"\/Date(1304370000000)\/",
                         "typeId":1
                       }
                  ],
                  "numberOfItems":2
              }
          ]
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is the string-literal that would be in C# source for such JSON. It's not so useful to show the string-literal form; if anything is to be shown, show the *real* JSON value, unless there is a reason to do otherwise. Anyway, after *downloading the distributable*, read the CHM helpfile that comes with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create some entity like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int MessageType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<EntityValue> Value { get; set; }
}

public class EntityValue
{
    public int listId { get; set; }
    public string listName { get; set; }
    public List<ItemInList> itemInList { get; set; }
}

public class ItemInList
{
    public DateTime? fromDate { get; set; }
    public string fromLocation { get; set; }
    public string toLocation { get; set; }
    public string originalRequest { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    public int typeId { get; set; }
}
```

The entity must has the same structure like the json data.
And you can call the Method:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json);
```

If it has any exception,you need to adjust the entities until it works.

Comment: @Dozer, can you be more specific on how to call Item in the end please?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the below link for parsi in metro style application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770287.aspx

Comment: Can you summarize the info that you are linking to?