# PHP webservice return mixed data how can i use it in c#

Tags: c#, php, web-services

i have web service in php which contain method (login) that should return 
false or associated array !

iam trying to use it in c# , but c# keep telling me that i must use object to handle returned data and so i did , but i cant parse anything of data

this is a glimpse of code

```
        object user;
        user = Chat.login(txtUsername.Text,txtPassword.Text);

        if (user.Equals(false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error !");
        }
        else {
           //i wanna here for example show user['name'] for example
        }
```

the above code works fine if user entered wrong data , and if it's in system
it return mixed data (array of user data) 
but i can't use it

Comment: What sort of data in what format does the PHP service return? JSON? Please show the raw output that you are trying to parse.

Comment: Fire up a debugger and hover over the `user` when the login was successful. What type is it of?

Comment: you know webservice return xml data

Comment: It sounds like you've implemented the php webservice yourself, in which case you should return a fixed type or null, rather than false. (I think c# will handle/understand null).

Comment: @BobDavies i use zend web service tool and it works very fine with all other data types that is not array ?

Comment: In that case... what @shiplu.mokadd.im said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite the webservice so that it returns an object instead of two different types.  In JSON it should look like,

```
{"status": "SUCCEDED", "result": [1,2,3,4]} // valid login
{"status": "FAILED"} // valid login
```

Then you can check if status is `"SUCCEDED"`.

Another approach is to return an array. On success return associative array. On failure return an **empty** array. This allows you to check the length of the array to determine the success.

```
[1,2,3,4] // valid login
[] // valid login
```

The example is in JSON. You can convert it to XML anyway. Most important thing is that you should have got the idea.

Comment: the problem is i want to parse this object to extract data from it,

Comment: as you mentioned now it returns this {"id":"4","u_name":"samymassoud","u_password":"47dffd4ae5531f11cc791a0748ef2f3edc4aea93","u_email":"samymassoud@gmail.com","u_mobile":"111111","u_blocknumber":"1249","is_active":"1","u_type":"1","u_date":"2011-08-05","u_time":"1312567660","last_time":"11:07 AM","last_date":"2012-07-06","project":"0","last_login":""} i want to deal with this in c# how can i do ?

Comment: @SamyMassoud You can use JSON.NET to parse JSON. See (the only answer to this question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963079/parse-json-object-in-c-sharp]

Comment: thank you, i figured out a solution based on your answer so i will mark it as best answer :D but iam troubleshooting an other thing is A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server i will search for it ,and if i can't find answer i will post it here , so if  have any suggestions don't hist-ate to answer me ,Thank you